# How to get the screen size of monitor in Windows Form application for capturing screenshots?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, screenshot, multiple-monitors

I am working on a solution which grabs the screenshot and saves it in the form of image at regular intervals. This application is built in Windows Forms.

I have used the below code to get the screen resolution -:

```
int h = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
int w = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
```

This works fine in a laptop with 1366 * 768 resolution.

But the image gets cropped off from right and bottom side when the same application is executed on a very large monitor.

Is there a way to handle the monitor size in the code.

Comment: ["The working area is the desktop area of the display, excluding taskbars, docked windows, and docked tool bars."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea). [`Screen.Bounds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.bounds) can be used instead to get the whole screen

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to capture the screen containing the form, use the [Screen.FromControl method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.fromcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx), passing it the form instance, and then use the WorkingArea of that screen.

If this assumption is wrong, please add more detail to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This code does multiple screens... its what I use...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace JeremyThompsonLabs
{
    public class Screenshot
    {
        public static string TakeScreenshotReturnFilePath()
        {
            int screenLeft = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Left;
            int screenTop = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Top;
            int screenWidth = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width;
            int screenHeight = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height;

            // Create a bitmap of the appropriate size to receive the screenshot.
            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight))
            {
                // Draw the screenshot into our bitmap.
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    g.CopyFromScreen(screenLeft, screenTop, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
                }

                var uniqueFileName = Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName().Replace(".", string.Empty) + ".jpeg");
                try
                {
                    bitmap.Save(uniqueFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return string.Empty;
                }
                return uniqueFileName;
            }
        }

    }
}
```